# Preserving generic types through another generic type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-testing-library

I'm considering submitting a patch (or patches) of the type declarations in [`@testing-library/react`](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) and/or [`@testing-library/dom`](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library).  Currently, all queries on `RenderResult` return variants of `HTMLElement`, which leaves me writing a lot of code like

```ts
const myDiv = wrapper.getByText('some text') as HTMLDivElement;
```

The simplest solution is to make the queries generic.

```ts
export type GetByText = <T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(/* ... */) => T
export const getByText: GetByText
```

Then I can just do:

```ts
const myDiv = wrapper.getByText<HTMLDivElement>('some text');
```

While this works in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAilC8UA8AVKEAewIDsAmAzlABIoCyAMgKIA2EAtrsAiedXYzsAHwAUAlAm5QUAbgBQeCAGMaAQwBO0aQHscBZgEcAXLAnjV65ngCWANxaakpSgBFztBkz79RQA), something in `@testing-library/react` is preventing the generic form from being passed along to `RenderResult`'s methods.

These are the relevant snippets of the current versions of `@testing-library/react` and `@testing-library/dom`.

#### `@testing-library/dom`

**types/queries.d.ts**

```ts
export type GetByText = (
  container: HTMLElement,
  id: Matcher,
  options?: SelectorMatcherOptions,
) => HTMLElement

export const getByText: GetByText
```

**types/get-queries-for-element.d.ts**

```ts
import * as queries from './queries';

export type BoundFunction<T> = T extends (
    attribute: string,
    element: HTMLElement,
    text: infer P,
    options: infer Q,
) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q) => R
    : T extends (a1: any, text: infer P, options: infer Q, waitForElementOptions: infer W) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q, waitForElementOptions?: W) => R
    : T extends (a1: any, text: infer P, options: infer Q) => infer R
    ? (text: P, options?: Q) => R
    : never;
export type BoundFunctions<T> = { [P in keyof T]: BoundFunction<T[P]> };

export type Query = (
    container: HTMLElement,
    ...args: any[]
) => Error | Promise<HTMLElement[]> | Promise<HTMLElement> | HTMLElement[] | HTMLElement | null;

export interface Queries {
    [T: string]: Query;
}

export function getQueriesForElement<T extends Queries = typeof queries>(
    element: HTMLElement,
    queriesToBind?: T,
): BoundFunctions<T>;
```

#### `@testing-library/react`

(may or may not be relevant)
**types/index.d.ts**

```ts
export type RenderResult<
  Q extends Queries = typeof queries,
  Container extends Element | DocumentFragment = HTMLElement
> = {
  // ...
} & {[P in keyof Q]: BoundFunction<Q[P]>}
```

Alongside the change I made above, making each query's type generic, I changed `Query` in `get-queries-for-element.d.ts`:

```ts
export type Query = <T extends HTMLElement>(
    container: HTMLElement,
    ...args: any[]
) => Error | Promise<T[]> | Promise<T> | T[] | T | null;
```

I'm nearly certain the issue is in `BoundFunction` or `getQueriesForElement()`, as when I made these  changes (which I am like 37% confident are right), I get an error:

> ```
> Type 'typeof import(".../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries")' does not satisfy the constraint 'Queries'.
>   Property 'getByLabelText' is incompatible with index signature.
>     Type 'GetByText' is not assignable to type 'Query'.
>       Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'T | Error | T[] | Promise<T[]> | Promise<T>'.
>         Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>           'HTMLElement' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'HTMLElement'. ts(2344)
> ```

There might be another problem in `@testing-library/react` (and thus, the other testing-library packages), but fixing this is the first step.

Part of my problem is that I don't actually understand what `BoundFunction` is doing.  What do I need to do to make make `typeof queries` satisfy the `Queries` constraint?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirkxQGsk4BnXZ0SWF8gEyTQAbFETgA7FCCQsw6ZmCIwYATwBi0ECngBvcnH1wVYZgHkwMYBDEtkaJMABuSXnAC8cFGOUUAvnwHCokbMAMpIggIw0ACyWmgAFkhQZhZWLG4eXhT8QiLMwXCxMAlJGZ7elDmBzGhp8ACOAK5JwNIAXHC6BnAA5kgwAELKACpIAB4wHQDi-UOjE74U1ABUy3AAArwQaI1SYvDrMNIWYj0AtILAAEZQIspUWyBUwSxUTS3SAHS8nzDpy1RKOMuPACjNBiNxvB3AAeYZwKFIMS8dIACWG0QAMgBRCJ7aFwdFY3FIfEAPgAFHo4LV9ihgGIkh0iTi8UiYAAaanAXgdIolKBc-QQcyWawAfg6YQiGBicUSyVFaS5AEo3GS4MNKFRVhstjt8RsjiwTudLjc7g9cM9lMZXn0YGd3lBWiwzphoGdwqT2d9fv9AeRgdBQbbmAMII1kaooxgxXCNe54Yjkekqd0tDAXVdGkcOiaXachQZvfjmRjWT79sX9EcJh0GZhSgAFGtwEWpawNsRNqBwACKqvVcEbpQQ1P04rgFLrkzgrfbSolHX7atcGvH3Q6yYmSJR05QAEYOuUOYYod3e-Ozx2xSxL6VB3AAO70mDqKAk-EpO8PvsAdTXDVRz7TcDCnGcL2vRdOxYSUBzPV9gHfaAv3ZH80ngwDhzA-RtwRXdUwPY9MmUM9Zz-aDbzSSjV2HEDEAnOAIIoqilzglcgMYrdxCQJwoAoYNYEMMM4AjKNeBjMQ4zSBMMm0OAAG1mxHMQ4CYZQIEwTUAF0OnE6NY07OFlJ0jUfCWITQ2MAdmigZQMjhAijiIlk0P2SkmNpGB6UZKBy2JNlqyYz5QpEHp71IxSdPILjsSgHA+wAH3nHAQGAFgkBMsy4BS5s0oyrLhg1FLhmi3LNQqsRGkEQRLLGEFVKOKB6DsWyPnSLoDEU4Z8yzBkej09r7N8SoAjyOgjLFXp+n7OzXQ-dyYCclN9zmjqMmCLS4GdV1PO6Ut2QCyt8TbXbpGGCABgZXh4OGVV9MjQzpNghMlh1NZNm2XZ2SNY4Boua5bnsqgiHQGAbTtKgbvGP0-jgAEgQakMRJs5BkSSZAWBq5bqX7Zy93SdaXWkTaw2286WGLABhKwfIZUpVvSJaKoAEW+-FVFuHpDXcNygpgchE06alvN8pk4FpukGagakrhQTKlo6JbqX4HMeg6dMDHlxWBclJj9BSlXukNuB2YNdkuZQHn2QNiqAEEEpQZQYRZlLzZ+-YrZtjy200MZMSRHoYHieDqpAK4kjbajlzgBR+hUD9NBgT4MOsWx7CcXhiy4hwIB5akiCIDH-OnRpgA6ZBwc+KuMCW3P894akoxAJ65wpBuC-0BXvbLacuI9znufxcgfDgAAyTplNU9SkE07T+yGgzJKmqwYX7UyyR8IA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a design limitation of TypeScript, although I haven't found a narrowly applicable issue in GitHub.  The general issue is that the heuristics TypeScript uses to check assignability between two types do not perform true [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134) for a discussion about the possibility of implementing such unification in TypeScript.

The shortest example I can come up with of the problem you're facing is this:

```
declare const genFn: <T extends 0>() => T;
const widerGenFn: <T extends 0>() => T | 1 = genFn; // error!
// Type '<T extends 0>() => T' is not assignable to type '<T extends 0>() => T | 1'.
// Type '0' is not assignable to type 'T | 1'
```

The function `genFn()` has a type parameter `T` that is constrained to the numeric literal type `0`, takes no function parameters, and returns a value of type `T`.  The function `widerGenFn()` is exactly the same, except that it returns a value of type `T | 1`.

If someone replaced `widerGenFn` with `genFn` behind your back, you should not notice; if you call `widerGenFn<ABC>()`, you will expect a value of type `ABC | 1` back, and the fact that `genFn` returns a value of type `ABC` won't bother you, because every value of type `ABC` is also a value of type `ABC | 1`.  This implies that the type of `genFn` *should* be [assignable to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/understanding-errors.html#assignable-to) the type of `widerGenFn`.

But it's not.  TypeScript complains that `Type '<T extends 0>() => T' is not assignable to type '<T extends 0>() => T | 1'`, because `Type '0' is not assignable to type 'T | 1'`.  What gives?

Well, when comparing generic functions like this, the compiler does not use so-called "higher kinded types" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  It seems to immediately substitute a specific type for `T` in the target type.  So for `genFn`, the compiler changes `<T extends 0>() => T` and just replaces `T` with its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), `0`.  So `genFn` is seen as being type `() => 0`, which is not assignable to `<T extends 0>() => T | 1`.

And there's an error.

This means you also get errors when trying to use [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), since `type X<T extends U = V>` will require that `V extends U`:

```
type GenFn = typeof genFn;
type WiderGenFn = typeof widerGenFn
type Foo<T extends WiderGenFn = GenFn> = void; // error!
// ---------------------------> ~~~~~
```

---

So what's the workaround?  I'm not sure... it probably will depend strongly on the use cases.  One way is to "widen" the constraint to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of both types involved:

```
type Bar<T extends WiderGenFn | GenFn = GenFn> = void; // okay
```

(in your case this would look like `Q extends Queries | typeof queries = typeof queries`)

There may be other ways to sidestep the lack of unification in TypeScript, but I wouldn't be surprised to see strange side effects and edge cases pop up.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gcxCgYigFzwA8AKvCAB4Z7BrwAMAfABQCU8AvC-OQG4AUMnRYA7gEtQMAOJ5CJClVr1GrTjz6UAPvACMPHApQD4AenNUYMJDACEQy-wCeABwQByJp-iTGKEhYUGhoktgoUABGEAgYSPAY7l66Bp5CQkke8PIEKEZZIEgAZsZ5woXwAOrSIHImBckl8FIyuYSZyfD4SEjKNHQoDNW19XlG7Sh83PAAbkjSZs51tjBOVgC0W9s7u3t7fAB+x8cZlQBCsP2qQ4w1bQ16kxMm03MLwBVdlwBe14PDe51Z4zf5qeAAVxQAGtAuIpppePw3vNFkIgA)